# Why are both `p()` and `(*p)()` valid?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, function-pointers, history

Say for this simple code:

```
int foo(void);
int (*p)(void);
p = foo;
p = &foo;
int a = p();
int b = (*p)();
```

In the above example, Line 3&4 are both valid, Line 5&6 are also both valid.

In fact if you try to play with variable pointers like that when you play with function pointers, your program will surely die. So why is it valid for function pointers?

Comment: Because the language explicitly allows such a shortcut

Comment: There's really no other reason. It's provided for convenience because it's unambiguous.

Comment: is it because functions and variables are inherently different? say int f == 1 and &f will return to the pointer to it. but int foo(void) is a function. so you can only call it, or get a pointer to it. so p = &foo is the logical way to do this, but the compiler allows p = foo to be equivalent - returning the pointer to foo. this is a question, not a statement. :)

Comment: @slipperyseal. Basically. There is nothing ambiguous about the notation if you know the type of the left side.

Comment: Before the C standard, the only way to use function pointers to call a function was using the 'declaration mimics use' notation — `(*p)()`.  This matches the declaration notation — `int (*p)(void);`, except that you didn't have prototypes back in those days, so you'd have declared `int (*p)();`.  I learned that because there wasn't an alternative; I still use it because it is explicit.  While you could write `double r2 = (*sqrt)(2.0);`, there really isn't a benefit to doing so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function (more precisely, a *function designator*) is converted to a pointer to a function (except when it is the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or the unary `&`). So `foo` and `&foo` are the same thing because `foo` is automatically converted to `&foo`.

Similarly, `p` is a pointer to a function, so `*p` is the function, so it is automatically converted to the address of the function.

In fact, because `*p` is converted back to a pointer right away, you can apply `*` to it again, as in `int b = (**p)();`. And you can do that again and again and again: `int b = (************p)();`.

From the 2011 C standard (committee draft N1570), 6.3.2.1 4:

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type “function returning *type*” is converted to an expression that has type “pointer to function returning *type*”.

This is just a consequence of the fact that C developers wanted to make it easy to use both functions like `foo` and pointers-to-functions like `p`. If you had to write `foo()` for one and `(*p)()` for the other, that would be a bit of a nuisance. Or at least more typing. Or, if you had to write `(&foo)()` for one and `p()` for the other, that is again more typing. So they just said whenever you write a function, we will automatically make it the pointer, and you can call it without typing any more.

I suppose they could have said the function call operator can accept either a function or a pointer to a function, but they chose the automatic conversion instead.

Corollary: If you do not know whether something is a function, or a pointer to a function, or a pointer to a pointer to a function, *etc.*, just slap a hundred asterisks in front of it, and the compiler will stop when it gets to the function.

Comment: So do you mean `p = &&&&&&&&foo` is also a valid assignment?

Comment: @iBug: No; `foo` is automatically converted to `&foo`, but `&&foo` is not automatically converted to `&foo`. (`&&foo` isn't even valid, since `&foo` isn't an lvalue.)

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks for the notation. Actually I'm looking more for the reason why standard allows this than the fact that it's allowd.

Comment: @ruakh `&&foo` is not valid because the `&&` operator takes two operands

Comment: @M.M: Oh, good point. C++ no longer follows the "maximal munch" rule in all cases, but the OP is asking about C. :-)

Comment: @ruakh This case is not different in C++

Comment: @M.M: I don't see how you can be so sure. If it weren't for the issue I raised (that `&p` is not an lvalue), modern C++ might well allow `&&` as a synonym for `& &` when this is unambiguous, just as it allows `>>` as a synonym for `> >`. Unless you have a crystal ball that lets you see into parallel universes, it's not worth speculating about, let alone insisting upon.

Comment: @ruakh even better than a crystal ball, I have a copy of the C++ Standard which defines all of this stuff

Comment: @M.M: Unless that C++ Standard comes from the parallel universe where `&p` is an lvalue, I don't see why you think it's relevant!

Comment: @ruakh `&p`'s value category has nothing to do with the tokenization of `&&` .. Post a new question if you doubt it.

Comment: @M.M: Let me get this straight. You want me to post a question about the changes that C++ might make to its tokenization rules if it changed the value category of `&p` in a way that would make `& & p` meaningful? . . . Are you insane?

Comment: @ruakh no, I want you to understand that according to the C++ standard, `&&` is always parsed as a single token in C++ regardless of context. You seem to doubt my word and you seem disinclined to actually read the standard, so that leaves posting a question as another option. (NB. Will not respond to any more comments, this discussion is unproductive)

Comment: @M.M: I was aware from the beginning that in present-day C++, `&&` is always parsed as a single token. (Though obviously I overlooked that in my very first comment, hence your (very reasonable) first reply.) My point was simply that the reason for this is, in part, that there's no reason to allow it to be parsed otherwise. As evidence, I pointed to `>>`, which used to always be parsed as a single token, until the committee decided that was too restrictive. And that's when you started going off the deep end . . . anyway, have a nice day. :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to [§6.5.2.2/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p1) of the C11 Standard, in a function call:

> The expression that denotes the called function shall have type pointer to function returning void or returning a complete object type other than an array type.

Now, in most expressions a function designator is converted to a function pointer ([§6.3.2.1/4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p4)):

> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the **sizeof** operator, the **_Alignof** operator, or the unary **&** operator, a function designator with type ''function returning type'' is converted to an expression that has type ''pointer to function returning type''.

So, in a function call such as `int a = p();`, the function designator `p` is converted to a function pointer, which is needed in the expression before the postfix operator `()` for the function call.

But, according to [§6.5.3.2/4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4) about the indirection operator:

> If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator

So, in a function call such as `int b = (*p)();`, the function designator `p` is converted to a function pointer, and the result of the indirection operator acting on this function pointer is a function designator, which itself is converted to the function pointer needed in the postfix expression for the function call.

By §6.5.2.2/1 above, `foo` is converted to a function pointer in the expression `p = foo`. But, in the expression `p = &foo`, the function designator is *not* converted to a function pointer. Here, [§6.5.3.2/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p3) states that:

> The unary **&** operator yields the address of its operand. If the operand has type ''type'', the result has type ''pointer to type''.... Otherwise, the result is a pointer to the object or function designated by its operand.

So the expression `&foo` evaluates to a pointer to the function designated by `foo`, as expected.